# Multiplying partial derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, partial-derivative, implicit-differentiation, implicit-function-theorem

I am trying to understand what happens when I have a continuous differentiable function $f$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $f$($x_1,x_2,...x_n$) = 0.

What is the significance of the product:
$\frac{\delta x_n}{\delta x_1}\frac{\delta x_1}{\delta x_2}
\frac{\delta x_2}{\delta x_3}...\frac{\delta x_{n-1}}{\delta x_n} $.

Could someone help me with? Thank you very much!

Comment: I know it's an old post, but where did you see such expression?